# Compare every field in table to every other field in same table

Tags: sql, hive, hiveql

Imagine a table with only one column.

```
+------+
|  v   |
+------+
|0.1234|
|0.8923|
|0.5221|
+------+
```

I want to do the following for row K:

1. Take row K=1 value: 0.1234
2. Count how many values in the rest of the table are less than or equal  to value in row 1.

Iterate through all rows 
Output should be:

```
+------+-------+
| v    |output |
+------+-------+
|0.1234|   0   |
|0.8923|   2   | 
|0.5221|   1   | 
+------+-------+
```

*Quick Update* I was using this approach to compute a statistic at every value of v in the above table. The cross join approach was way too slow for the size of data I was dealing with. So, instead I computed my stat for a grid of v values and then matched them to the vs in the original data. v_table is the data table from before and stat_comp is the statistics table.

```
AS SELECT t1.* 
,CASE WHEN v<=1.000000 THEN pr_1 
WHEN v<=2.000000 AND v>1.000000 THEN pr_2 
FROM v_table  AS t1 
LEFT OUTER JOIN stat_comp AS t2
```

Comment: Welcome! I'm a little confused by the output. `0.5221 > 0.1234` so why does `output = 1` in that row?

Comment: Sorry typo. Should be correct now.

Comment: It almost seems like what you want is to count how many values are less than or equal to the current row, not less than or equal to row 1 specifically. Is that the case?

Comment: Yes, sorry. I'm at work and keep getting interrupted. Question should reflect the new changes. It is for every row that I want to run this comparison.

Comment: The data sample does not reflect well the issue you are dealing with and although you gave a plenty of explanations the required result is still not completely clear . If you require "less than or equal", there should be at least one repetition of a value in your data sample.

Answer (score 0):

Windows functions were added to ANSI/ISO SQL in 1999 and to to Hive in version 0.11, which was released on 15 May, 2013.
What you are looking for is a variation on **rank with ties high** which in ANSI/ISO SQL:2011 would look like this-

```
rank () over (order by v with ties high) - 1
```

Hive currently does not support `with ties ...` but the logic can be implemented using `count(*) over (...)`

---

```
select  v
       ,count(*) over (order by v) - 1 as rank_with_ties_high_implicit

from    mytable
;
```

or

```
select  v
       ,count(*) over 
        (
            order by v
            range between unbounded preceding and current row            
        )  - 1  as rank_with_ties_high_explicit

from    mytable
;
```

Comment: As far as I can tell, my answer is still correct, though yours may be faster. Why the downvote?

Comment: @McGlothlin - As you can see I was a little distracted by other things :-) Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Generate sample data

```
select 0.1234 as v into #t
union all
select 0.8923
union all
select 0.5221
```

This is the query

```
;with ct as (
    select ROW_NUMBER() over (order by v) rn
    , v
    from #t ot
)
select distinct v, a.cnt
from ct ot
    outer apply (select count(*) cnt from ct where ct.rn <> ot.rn and v <= ot.v) a
```

Comment: The post is tagged with `hive` but even for SQL Server this is bad solution. **(1)** This could be answered with a single windows function without using `outer apply` **(2)**  The `row_number` is totally unnecessary. All you need to do is to subtract 1 from the `count(*)`

Answer (score -1):

After seeing your edits, it really does look look like you could use a Cartesian product, i.e. `CROSS JOIN` here. I called your table `foo`, and crossed joined it to itself as `bar`:

```
SELECT foo.v, COUNT(foo.v) - 1 AS output
FROM foo
CROSS JOIN foo bar
WHERE foo.v >= bar.v
GROUP BY foo.v;
```

[Here's a fiddle.](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/f43af/33)

This query cross joins the column such that every permutation of the column's elements is returned (you can see this yourself by removing the `SUM` and `GROUP BY` clauses, and adding `bar.v` to the `SELECT`). It then adds one count when `foo.v >= bar.v`, yielding the final result.

Comment: Since windows functions are part of the SQL standard for about 18(!) years, there in no reason what so ever to implement `rank` using a `cross join`. That alone justifies a down-vote.  In addition - **(1)** you have ignored the OP request for "less than **or equal**" **(2)** This is bad filtering placing. Putting the filtering in the aggregate function instead of the **where** clause, generates a row set of **n^2** rows instead of **((1+n)*n)/2**

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I've updated accordingly, but kept the `CROSS JOIN` because I think it gives an example of how to use one in case OP didn't know.

Answer (score -2):

You can take the full Cartesian product of the table with itself and sum a case statement:

```
select a.x
, sum(case when b.x < a.x then 1 else 0 end) as count_less_than_x
from (select distinct x from T) a
, T b
group by a.x
```

This will give you one row per unique value in the table with the count of non-unique rows whose value is less than this value.

Notice that there is neither a join nor a where clause. In this case, we actually want that. For each row of `a` we get a full copy aliased as `b`. We can then check each one to see whether or not it's less than `a.x`. If it is, we add 1 to the count. If not, we just add 0.

Comment: While "Cartesian product" was the first thing that came to mind based on the question, that's not actually what this does. A Cartesian product of this column would show every permutation of each element of `v`, if I'm not mistaken. Regardless, +1 for the sum/case approach.

Comment: This returns incorrect result if we have duplicate values in table.

Comment: The OP didn't explicitly specify distinct values. Whether or not that's "incorrect" depends on what the OP wants. I can just as easily imagine a situation in which you'd want to count each instance of a duplicate row as you would to only count it once. If you want distinct, it's easy to modify. Just replace the table aliased as b with a subquery (select distinct x from T).

Comment: This seems to work. However, this seems like it could slow down dramatically on a large table.

Comment: @mymarkers That's right, I want to count duplicate values.

Comment: What kind of database (e.g. Oracle, SQL Server, MySql, etc) is this? With standard SQL, any approach to this will ultimately do roughly the same thing. Some databases might have built-in functions that could do this, but the names and syntax vary slightly.